# Sending parameters to a maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

In my pom file I execute a build plugin with this configuration.

Can I access customProp from inside the plugin code?

```
<execution>
...
  <configuration>
    <configOptions>
      <additional-properties>useTags=true</additional-properties>
    </configOptions>
    <customProp>custom-value</customProp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumming that you are developing the plugin...

Yes, it is possible. Check [Parameters](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) section Maven's plugin development guide.

You have to define a property in your Mojo:

```
@Parameter( property = "your-plugin.customProperty", defaultValue = "custom" )
private String customProperty;
```

Comment: What exactly is the `your-plugin` string? Seems from the example that it's the goal I define in the project?

Comment: It is not being recognized, any idea why that may be?

Comment: "your-plugin" is the prefix of the parameter name if you want to pass it via command line (with -D)

Comment: I did `<configuration><name>value</name></configuration>` in my project pom. In the plugin I did `@Parameter(property="name")`, also tried `@Parameter(property="generate.name")`

Comment: Actually, I did `property="${name}"`, maybe that's my problem?

Comment: Tried, Still nothing

Comment: Can you show how it would be used in the pom of another project?

Comment: In case some others are looking for an explanation, the `your-plugin` in this answer refers to the `name` attribute of the `@Mojo` annotation. If you check the official doc in this answer, they use `sayhi` as the name. Search on the page with `"sayhi` and you will see there are 2 occurrences, one in `@Mojo` and one in `@Parameter`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, when you configure `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and building your application, you can access information about your application's build through `BuildProperties` object like -

```
@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

and read like -

```
// Artifact's name from the pom.xml file
buildProperties.getName();
// Artifact version
buildProperties.getVersion();
```

If predefined properties are not enough, you can pass your own properties from `pom.xml` file to  `BuildProperties`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>    
                <additionalProperties>                    
                      <java.version>${java.version}</java.version>                    
                      <some.custom.property>some value</some.custom.property>                
               </additionalProperties>            
            </configuration>        
     </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can pass a value directly or use your custom properties defined in the `<properties>` section of your `pom.xml` and then referenced using `${property.name}` placeholder.

You can access custom properties defined this way by calling  `buildProperties.get("property.name").`

Comment: In your example it would be `buildProperties.get("some.custom.property")`?

Comment: Apparently there is an issue https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8663